# Choosing an existing resource group gives error

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, azure-marketplace

When I try to deploy my solution on MS azure using an existing resource group it gives me an error as follows:

*"This resource group contains existing resources.Choose an empty resource group or create a new one".*

Can someone point how can I fix the error in CreateUIdefination.json or something else I need to do.

[image]

Comment: i dont think its allowed to deploy managed application to resource groups with resources, create a new empty group and it will work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the message, we can't create that resource to that resource group which contains existing resources, we should create a **new** resource group, or use an **empty** resource group.

As 4c74356b41 said, by default, Azure not support to deploy managed application to resource group with resources.

Please try to use **an empty resource group** to deploy it.

Comment: Yes *deploying to an empty resource group* works fine. Was wondering why this works for some of the marketplace offering(Try launching ubuntu VM). But doesn't work for some of them(custom solution templates).

Comment: Ubuntu VM is Azure IaaS, we can create them in the same resource group(same vnet), but SaaS can't custom define virtual network.

Comment: Ok. Got it. Thanks!!

Comment: I already have a VM inside an old resource group. Now I want to add docker container on same RG. But it doesn't allows me, instead it asks me to create new RG. If I create a new RG, then it will create a new VM ? and add docker container in it ?